# Use variable to SELECT records in a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am trying to select records from an Access table using a String variable from the result of a ComboBox selection.  I have confirmed the variable (zBEN) contains the correct data when selected.  If I manually enter the data in the `WHERE` part of the statement it works perfectly.  If I use zBEN it crashes - I get an error if I don't use the single quotes and I get an empty record set if I use the quotes.  The error is 3061, Too few parameters. Expected 1.  This error is usually a data type mismatch or incorrect field name.

```vb
Private Sub cmdDisplayMembers_Click()
'this displays a record in the dataset - from button click
Dim dbsContacts As DAO.Database
Dim rcdContacts As DAO.Recordset
Dim conArray As Variant              'this is the record array
Dim intArraySize As Integer         'array size
Dim iCtr As Integer                 'counter
Dim zBEN As Variant
Dim zName, strSQL  As String
zBEN = Me.cbxMembersList

Set dbsContacts = CurrentDb
'this statement works: (and has the combobox value manually entered
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = '201208FEAR' ORDER BY id_members"
'this statement gives an error 3061, 1:
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = zBEN ORDER BY id_members"
'this statement gives an empty record set
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = 'zBEN' ORDER BY id_members"

Set rcdContacts = dbsContacts.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If Not rcdContacts.EOF Then
    rcdContacts.MoveFirst              'start the counter at Row #1
    intArraySize = rcdContacts.RecordCount
    iCtr = 1
    ReDim conArray(10)

    Do Until rcdContacts.EOF
        conArray(iCtr) = rcdContacts.Fields("member_info")
        Debug.Print "Item: "; iCtr & " " & conArray(iCtr)

        iCtr = iCtr + 1
        rcdContacts.MoveNext
    Loop
MsgBox ("Error no records")
End If

If IsObject(rcdContacts) Then Set rcdContacts = Nothing
txtCon1 = conArray(1)
txtCon2 = conArray(2)
MsgBox (zBEN)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the criteria in quotes if it's a string. i.e.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = '" & zBEN & "' ORDER BY id_members"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the variable's value instead of its name into the SQL statement text as Wayne already suggested:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = '" & zBEN & "' ORDER BY id_members"
```

But if you switch to a parameter query approach, you needn't bother about the quotes:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMember_Contact where id_members = [which_id] ORDER BY id_members"
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = dbsContacts.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL )
qdf.Parameters("which_id").Value = Me!cbxMembersList.Value
Set rcdContacts = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```